# Is there a maximal finite subgroup $H$ of a virtually polycylcic group $G$ such that $h(G/H)=h(G)$?

Tags: group-theory

‎The *Hirsch length*‎, ‎$h(G)$‎, ‎of a virtually polycyclic group is finite and equal to $n\geq 0$‎, ‎if $G$ has a series $1=H_0 \lhd \cdots \lhd H_r =G$ in which the factors are either locally finite or infinite cyclic‎, ‎and exactly $n$ factors are infinite cyclic‎. ‎In all other cases‎, ‎$h(G)=\infty$. ‎Recall that a group is *locally finite* if all its finitely generated subgroups are finite‎.

We know that if $h(G)=0$ iff $G$ is finite.

My question: Is there a maximal normal finite subgroup $H$ of a virtually polycyclic group $G$ such that $G=H\rtimes N$ such that $h(G)=h(N)$?

By the fact that $h(G)=0$ iff $G$ is finite, in fact I want to remove the effect of role of the finite section of $G$ from the definition of Hirsch length.

Comment: The reference to locally finite groups is irrelevant and confusing. The factors $H_{i+1}/H_i$ in a virtually polycyclic group are either finite or infinite cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the finite normal subgroups of a virtually polycyclic group generate a finite normal subgroup, there is a unique maximal finite normal subgroup.

But it does not necessarily have a complement. I think the group $G=\langle x,y \mid y^4=1, y^{-1}xy=x^{-1} \rangle$ is a counterexample to your question. The maximal finite normal subgroup is $\langle y^2 \rangle$, but it has no complement in $G$.

Comment: Dear @DerekHolt , appreciate your nice answer. By your comments, there exists a unique maximal finite normal subgroup $N$ of a virtually polycyclic group $G$. Because $h(G)=h(N)+h(G/N)$ and $h(N)=0$, we have $h(G)=h(G/N)$. This is what I want. Just one more question: is $G/N$ torsion free or of finite cohomological dimendion?

Comment: $G/N$ is not torsion free in the example. It has the element $yN$ of order $2$.

Comment: That's right. Thank you very much for your help.